# Generate dynamic series in select query with computed value

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Context :**

A value arises to new set of values based on the observation coefficient of that value.

e.g. value **A** will create new sets of values **A-1, A-2, A-3** when the user clicks some button to create, but before that, I need to provide them a preview.

**Problem:**

If I have this table initially:

```
id  | value | observation
-----------------------------------------------
 1  | A     | 3
-----------------------------------------------
 2  | B     | 2
```

I wish to display a computed set of new values to be added based on observation value (a preview before confirmation) to look like this:

```
id   | value | new value to be created | observation
-----------------------------------------------
1    | A     | A-1                     |   3
-----------------------------------------------
1    | A     | A-2                     |   3
-----------------------------------------------
1    | A     | A-3                     |   3
```

It's like joining a table with another table containing the computed values without the having the actual table/relation yet.

What my thoughts are :

1. create a temporary table where the computed values are and then do the join (but what if the number of rows is too large, it would be costly to insert a lot everytime)
2. I've tried having the computed values as an array aggregate, but i need them in separate rows like the 2nd table i've shown.

How can I do this? Or is this even possible?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  You really should tag with only one.

Comment: sorry,, removing it.

Comment: Just to confirm, B will create B-1 and B-2 ? Because observation is 2?

Comment: yes Juan Carlos Oropeza.

Comment: did we answer your question muffin ?

Comment: hold on.. i'm still trying to recreate the solution for the actual problem.. it's not straight forward as i've asked it, as i have other columns, and tables in other relations. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) function and try this :

```
select 
    t.id, 
    t.value, 
    CASE 
      WHEN t.observation = 0 OR t.observation IS NULL THEN
        NULL
    ELSE 
        t.value || '-' || series.n
    END 
    as "new value to be created",
    t.observation
from 
    (select 
       s.n 
     from 
       generate_series(1,(select max(observation) from tableName)) as s(n)
    ) as series
cross join
   tableName as t  
where
   ((t.observation = 0 OR t.observation IS NULL) AND series.n = 1)
   OR 
   (series.n <= t.observation)
order by 
   t.value, 
   series.n
```

Comment: this is really good, except i didn't specify another problem (my bad) , problem with cross join. The row is not displayed if the observation value is empty or 0. it should still be included as a single row.. but with the new value to be created set as null. is there any way to get around this?

Comment: yes.. this is actually correct.. and i accepted this answer because the other one has generate_series(1,20) with the value "20" hardcoded, i tried changing it to "5" and the output changes adjusts to it to, so it was technically wrong. thank you very much,

Comment: there might be a bug or something i missed,...the problem is the row is generated max(observation) times... like example A has 0 observation, but throughout the table, the max value is 80... then it returns A-* rows 80 times.

Comment: a bug in the where clause. I changed it take a look and try it. Now, I have to go to sleep :p I had fun answering your question but I can't answer all the questions you add in this post...

Comment: yes thank you.. it's all good. no more follow ups.. thanks for lending me some sleep time..haha..

Answer (score 0):

Here SQL will useful to you.

```
select id, value,value ||'-'|| number as "new value to be created" ,observation
from (
select 1 as number
union
select 2  
union
select 3 
union
select 4) as t, context  where t.number <= observation
```

Here dynamic generate number SQL

```
select id, value,value ||'-'|| generate_series as "new value to be created" ,
observation
from (
select * from generate_series(1, 20)) as t, context  where t.generate_series <= observation
```

[Here SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/89c0f/17)

Thank you.